# Run asynchronous callback in http::geturl

Tags: tcl, asynchronous

I try to run  **http::geturl** asynchronously, and obtain it results inside callback.I have this code

```
package require  http

proc cb {token} {
    exec notify-send "message";
    puts "console message"
    exec  echo  "file message" >  ~/test_file    
}

http::geturl  http://mail.ru   -command  cb
```

When i run this code like  **tclsh main.tcl** nothing happens - script works but dont  call  callback

When i run this code like **wish  main.tcl** all works fine, i see "message" notification, see "console message", and test_file gets "file message"

Why this happens and how i should run tcl scripts asynchronously??

Comment: This is described in the documentation, and a convenience command,  ::http::wait, exists to facilitate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must enter Tcl's event loop at the appropriate position (after having registered the callbacks etc.) explicitly using `vwait`:

```
package require  http

proc cb {token} {
    puts "console message"
    set ::done 1; # break out of event loop
}

http::geturl http://example.org/ -command cb

vwait ::done; # enter the event loop
```

Within the callback, you may want to leave the event loop, again, by setting the signal variable `::done`.

Comment: `wish` enters the event loop implicitly, therefore, the difference.